# Use PHP to get JSON data from REST API

Tags: php, json, rest

I'm new in REST API. I'm building up a test environment and trying to make a handshake between Rest API and Client side PHP.

My JSON data is at

> http://localhost:50417/api/device

the data is like:

```
    [
    {"Truck_ID":1,"Company":"Food Mall","Distance":2000},   
    {"Truck_ID":2,"Company":"Food Mall","Distance":4000},
    {"Truck_ID":3,"Company":"Food Mall","Distance":3050}
    ]
```

I'm trying to act like a client, use PHP to get the data, and put the data in an array. What I tried on client side which is http://localhost:8080 is

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost:50417/api/device";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
echo $response;
?>
```

I also tried js like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("http://localhost:50417/api/device",
    function(data){
           alert (data) // this will show your actual json array
      });
    });

</script>
```

But no matter what I tried, I always get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." What could be the problem? How clients generally get the data from server using REST API? Thank you.

Comment: Can you view `http://localhost:50417/api/device` in a browser?  JavaScript may give you a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error, but PHP's `file_get_contents` shouldn't.  What error do you get with the PHP code?

Comment: You are right. PHP can see it. I forgot to delete JS file so I thought it is a problem of CORS. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

allow cross origin requests

Enable it in the .htaccess by putting the below line

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

or try from php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$url = "http://localhost:50417/api/device";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Pretty sure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header that's set on the *server*.

Comment: Also, pretty sure PHP doesn't care about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header sent from the server.  It's only JavaScript that cares about CORS requests.  He needs to show the PHP error he is getting because it certainly is a different one from the JavaScript.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat is right. Thank you guys. I won't consider add an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to server. But Feroz gives me an idea to show JSON data without PHP. Thank you.